# how to get rid of beamer "navigation toolbar"

Tags: latex, beamer

The latex file is defined as follows

```
\documentclass[center]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
```

Obviously I have tried the existing solution to remove the navigation toolbar, but in the full screen mode, the toolbar still exists. I don't want the beamer shows the total number of slides. How can I remove it?

[image]

As a follow-up, I found out some past posts to deal with this problem, and now it works:)

```
\documentclass[center]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%   no page number/total number of slides
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
%    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} % DELETED
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Basically, first I have to redefine footline by commenting out the "insert frame number", then I need to remove the "presentation" mode wrapping the madrid theme. Without either step, it won't work.

---

I just found out that on my mac, the above modification still won't work if I click the "full screen" from "edit". The simple solution is actually to enter the full screen by using the keyboard -- "command+shift+L". That will do even without the above modifications.

Comment: The page numbers aren't part of the navigation symbols! The page numbers are put there by the beamertheme you use. It might have an option to disable them, check its documentation

Comment: Thanks! Once I figured out it was not "navigation symbols" but "page number", I have googled out a desirable solution. Now it works!